# Running a java app with conditional argument on a mac

Tags: java, macos

I have written a java app that needs to connect to an external 32 bits library.

On my iMac (Intel), I need to launch the jar file with the -d32 option.

On my Powerbook G4, it has to be launched without the -d32 option.

I would like to create a bundle of my jar file that runs on both macs.
So there is some condition to test to decide to use or not use the -d32 option

How can I do that?

Comment: Just create two bundles, it's just one different `plist` entry - it might be possible to automate this. It's not very reasonable to expect a single app to be compatible with systems that different without changes.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer to my question:
First, the "-d32" option is not taken into account when the app is open by double clicking on it. So there is no more need to test the architecture before running the jvm.

In fact, it is very simple: on the Intel Mac, once the application is created, open the properties of the application, and select "open in 32 bits mode". That's all !!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties). Specifically `os.arch`. You can get a list of supported keys [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
System.out.println(arch);
```

on my system this will output 'amd64'. Once you know the arch you can then split your logic. 
If your using Java 7, then I would switch on the string:

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
System.out.println(arch);
switch(arch){
    case "amd64":
         //do logic
         break;
    default:
         //do default logic
         break;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to split the logic, if he needs a 32-bit native library his program just won't be able to work under amd64.

Comment: I'm not sure this going to help (directly).  The JVM has already being created, this "could" be used, however, to launch another JVM with the correct command line arguments - but I'm not sure what the command line argument is used for, so I might be wrong

Comment: @millimoose I read the post as "how can I determine what architecture I am executing on?" This would accomplish that. I used amd64 as my arch, depending on what machine he runs this one,it will return whatever arch is currently being executed against. Its a stab in the dark though - I've never coded cross architecture, so I have no idea if this would ultimately serve the OPS needs. MadProgrammers comment about launching another JVM might work though

Comment: @Robert H: I want to determine what architecture I am executing on BEFORE running the jvm so that I can launch the jvm with the correct option. I will look at MadProgrammers's solution